# How do you get the API key for Locu?

Tags: api, service

The documentation for `Locu` states that:

`To enable access to the Data API, developers need to create a profile and obtain their unique API key.`

Source: https://dev.locu.com/documentation/v1/

Problem is, I'm not sure on how to register in Locu, there is no registration section whatsoever. I tried going to the `developer portal` to register but it was no avail: https://locu.com/developers-and-partners/

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Hope this gets an answer soon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GoDaddy shut down new developer signups when they acquired Locu back in January 2017. Here's a post on the subject from GoDaddy support: https://www.godaddy.com/community/Developer-Cloud-Portal/Locu-API-Access/td-p/33447

Comment: can we get access to this API